# Applescript call python failed

Tags: python, shell, applescript

I have developed an AppleScript which needs to call a python file. i.e autorun.py the Autorun.py start with

```
import msoffcrypto
import pathlib
import os
....
```

Both the AppleScript and the python file run fine. I even tried to call autorun.py in the terminal and that also runs with no problem. But when the Applescript tried to call the python file:

```
set myPythonScript to POSIX path of "/Users/zhouyu/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/autounlock.py"

set myVal to do shell script "python" & space & myPythonScript's quoted form

display dialog myVal
```

It failed at the first line in the python code when Applescript tried to call it.

*error "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/zhouyu/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/autounlock.py", line 2, in 
import msoffcrypto
ImportError: No module named msoffcrypto" number 1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Terminal.app, `do shell script` does not read your shell profile so make sure you give it the full path to your `python` interpreter, e.g.:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3" & space & myPythonScript's quoted form
```